# Laravel Wherehas relationship with 2 records matching different values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on a bus route system. A route can have multiple stops (locations).

I have the following table structure:

**bus**

- id
- name
- route_id

**route**

- id
- name

**route_locations***

- id
- route_id
- place_id
- order
- start (start of the bus route - 1 = true, 0 = false)
- end (last stop - 1 = true, 0 = false)

**places**

- id
- name
- slug

So when someone does a search for a available bus we have a $from and $to in the form of a slug. Ex: from is 'location-a' and to is 'location-d'.

I'm trying to get back a collection of available busses that serve this route. I'm trying to do this in one query instead of having to loop through results again and match them against each other.

```
    $from = $request->from;
    $to = $request->to;

    $busses = Bus::whereHas('route', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
        $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->whereHas('place', function($query) use ($from, $to) {
                $query->where('slug', $from)
                    ->where('end', '!=', 1);
            })
                ->whereHas('place', function ($query) use ($to) {
                    $query->where('slug', $to)
                        ->where('start', '!=', 1);
            });
        });
    })->get();
```

route, locations and place are my relationships. They work fine.

When I delete the second whereHas('place') query, it will return a bus where the route has the correct starting location. But I'm trying to get only busses where the route has the 'from' location and to in the right 'order' where the 'from' is always lower than the 'to' location, if that makes sense? The next 'order' always needs to be higher.

I might be doing something wrong, as the above does not return the correct results. I'm not sure if it's even possible with eloquent to run a double whereHas on the same relationship.

Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: try using this code `$busses = Bus::whereHas('route.locations.place', function ($query) use ($from, $to) { $query->where('slug', $from)->where('end', '!=', 1);})->whereHas('route.locations.place', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {$query->where('slug', $to)->where('start', '!=', 1);})->get();`

Comment: The query works, but I already figured this out, but it still doesn't check if the 'order' column is higher than the previous one. The $to needs to have a 'order' column with a higher value than the $from. Thank you.